# Issue creating a bool JSON response in PDO | PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I currently have the following PDO script that simply select values from a mySQL database and displays them in JSON format as an array:

```
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('

    SELECT `part_record`
    FROM `Table1`
    WHERE `value_num` = 1 AND (`cust` = :cust)

    ');

  $stmt->execute([

      'cust' => $_POST['cust']

      ]);

  $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  echo json_encode($row);
```

Instead of displaying a list of records I would like response to simply be `{"error": false}` if the records are found and `{"error": true}` if no records are found.

Instead of doing `echo json_encode($row);` I have tried using bool like: `echo json_encode((bool) $row);` but this simply displays true or false and is displaying the opposite reponse of what I want.

Comment: Don’t fetchAll just fetch.

Comment: Check how many rows are found, if more than 0 true else false

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to select and fetch all the rows to do this. You can make your query count the number of rows matching the condition.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
    'SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `Table1`
    WHERE `value_num` = 1 AND (`cust` = :cust)'
);
$stmt->execute([
    'cust' => $_POST['cust']
]);
```

That way the query can return a single integer* value, rather than returning an array you aren't really going to use for anything other than checking if it's empty or not.

```
echo json_encode(['error' => !$stmt->fetchColumn()]);
```

You'll still need to convert the integer result to bool, but doing it this way should be much more efficient than fetching all the rows.

<sub>*Technically in your PHP code it will be a string containing an integer, but it will cast to bool the same way</sub>

Answer (score 1):

While you can cast an array to a boolean I prefer to be a bit more explicit. In this case I would use the `empty()` function.

For the format you want you will need to create an associative array for the output as well:

`echo json_encode( array( 'error' => empty($row) ) );`

Answer (score 0):

What about doing this:

```
echo json_encode(['error' => ! ( (bool) $row )] );
```